# Type Variables on methods

Tags: java, generics

I understand the concept of type variables to a certain point, that i can take a type that varies but then what is the difference between these two methods:

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(...);
```

and

```
public static List<T> toList(...);
```

as they both return a List of type T.

Comment: In the second example, what declares that type `T`? (hint: nothing, and that's why this won't compile)

Comment: The difference is that the second won't compile, since `T` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

In first case `T` is method's own type **parameter**, in the second case `T` is type parameter **value** of **instance** of the generic class on which you execute the method (in this case the code won't compile with `static` modifier) **or already existing** class/interface with name `T` (in this case it's not a type parameter in any sence).

Comment: You're assuming something not in evidence: That the class is generic, and defines `T`.

Comment: Even if it _were_ generic, this would be incorrect, as the method in the question was static. The class's generic parameters are only available at instance scope.

Comment: @yshavit The answer already covers the `static` aspect of the problem.

Comment: @PhilipVoronov Not really. Your statement *"in the second case `T` is type parameter value of instance of the generic class on which you execute the method"* still assumes that the owning class is generic. Nothing in the question says that.

Comment: @Andreas, I updated by appending 'or already existing'. Just consider options how the code can be interpreted depending on different contexts.

Comment: No. *"already existing class with name `T`"* is listing the unlikely case where there is a *class* named `T`. That is entirely different from a generic *type argument* named `T`, which is what your "second case" statement is assumingly talking about to.

Comment: @Andreas, it can be generic parameter only of the class it belongs to or existing class. Any cases more?

Comment: Existing interface. And if that's what you're trying to say, you should rephrase the answer to actually say that.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're saying:
For any type `T`, this method returns a List of `T`s.

The second only says:
This method returns a List of `T`s.

The distinction here is the "For any..." clause (which is the `<T>` you added after `static`). If you had a type named `T` already in scope, `T` would reference that; for example:

```
public class Something<T> {
    public List<T> doSomething() { ... }
}
```

This means that a `Something<T>` returns a `List<T>`. Specifically, both of these `T`s are referring to the same exact type, so `Something<Integer>` gives you `List<Integer>`. However, if you changed this to:

```
public class Something<T> {
    public <T> List<T> doSomething() { ... }
}
```

There are two different `T` types defined. As an example, calling `doSomething()` on a `Something<Integer>` could return `List<Random>` instead (because the two type variables don't have to be the same).

The other thing to consider: if there's a `class T`, `List<T>` would refer to that instead of the possible type variable if you didn't have a `<T>`. If there was no `class T` and no `<T>` anywhere, it would be an error (since `T` has to be introduced into "scope" at some point).

Comment: "Specifically, both of these Ts are referring to the same exact type" They're not. The first one is referring to a type parameter of the class; the second is a compiler error, because the method is static.

Comment: Whoops, accidentally left in `static` by accident when I was trying to show something different. For a `static` method, the main difference would be that `List<T>` now uses the type defined in `class T`.